# ERROR: no unpinned buffers available in postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I encountered an error in production environment while executing below query

```
ERROR:  no unpinned buffers available
STATEMENT:  SELECT product_id,  msisdn,EXPIRY_DATE, STATUS,PAY_SRC,PRODUCT_COST,START_DATE ,BEN_MSISDN, SRCCHANNEL,offer_id ,product_purchase_type  FROM RS_ADHOC_PRODUCTS  WHERE   msisdn =$1  AND segment_id =$2 AND PRODUCT_ID = $3 AND status != 4
ERROR:  no unpinned buffers available


ERROR:  no unpinned buffers available at character 13
QUERY:  INSERT INTO adhoc_segment_4 VALUES (NEW.*)

ERROR:  no unpinned buffers available at character 67
STATEMENT:  SELECT TRIGGER_NAME, TRIGGER_GROUP, NEXT_FIRE_TIME, PRIORITY FROM QRTZ_TRIGGERS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'ClusteredScheduler' AND TRIGGER_STATE = $1 AND NEXT_FIRE_TIME <= $2 AND (MISFIRE_INSTR = -1 OR (MISFIRE_INSTR != -1 AND NEXT_FIRE_TIME >= $3)) ORDER BY NEXT_FIRE_TIME ASC, PRIORITY DESC
```

Has anyone encountered same problem before

Comment: Postgres 9.2 is no longer maintained or supported. You should upgrade to a more recent version (9.6 or 10)

Comment: YES. several people have.  seems to be related to running out of resources.

Comment: Do you have a very low `shared_buffers` setting? Maybe increasing the parameter can help.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe yes it was the only problem i have provided the answer with analysis.Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution 
Specification of prod memory

```
MemTotal:       26312192 Kb (26GB)
MemFree:          869080 kB
MemAvailable:   17128440 kB
Buffers:          143184 kB
Cached:         17165500 kB
SwapCached:        11848 kB
Active:         10612320 kB
Inactive:       13494804 kB
Active(anon):    6793376 kB
Inactive(anon):  1452068 kB
Active(file):    3818944 kB
Inactive(file): 12042736 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       8388604 kB
SwapFree:        8288996 kB
Dirty:              9216 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       6789452 kB
Mapped:           225808 kB
Shmem:           1446824 kB
Slab:             863492 kB
SReclaimable:     651096 kB
SUnreclaim:       212396 kB
KernelStack:       21248 kB
PageTables:       181896 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    21544700 kB
Committed_AS:   11161456 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       83540 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359643136 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:   2160640 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      194560 kB
DirectMap2M:     5048320 kB
DirectMap1G:    22020096 kB
```

According to above settings postgres recommanded settings

[image]

In my current environment

shared buffer value was only 8 MB as shown below

```
show shared_buffers;
shared_buffers 
----------------
8MB
(1 row)
```

Thus change this value to recommanded value `6GB` this is calculated on basis of documentation from the postgres site.

[Shared Buffers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-SHARED-BUFFERS)

which stats that shared buffer reasonable value is 25% of the system.

Happy Reading!!